# How can I use voice recognition with other languages android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, recognizer-intent

I have a code that used to worked but for some reason it suddenly just stopped working, I'm trying to use voice recognition in Hebrew but it seems like since a few days ago it just starts voice recognition in English.

Here is my code

```
 sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getApplicationContext());
            test_voice_recognitiona listener = new test_voice_recognitiona();
            sr.setRecognitionListener(listener);
            Intent fl = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            fl.putExtra("android.speech.extra.LANGUAGE", "he");
            fl.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "he");
            fl.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                    this.getPackageName());
            sr.startListening(fl);
```

test_voice_recognitiona is the name of my RecognitionListener class name.

The code runs well but for some reason it keeps listening in English.

What am I doing wrong?

By the way I tried the simpler code with the google dialog and it's working.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "he");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Talk to Me " + user_name);
        startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

Perhaps it's the Google now update fault

Comment: Looks like a very recent issue. Also asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417439/speechrecognizer-with-google-search-version-3-6-14-1337016-cant-recognize-other

Comment: Yes, it is, do you have any idea of how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5):

Although I'm late to the party,
The following hack works for me:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "he");
    intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.EXTRA_ADDITIONAL_LANGUAGES", new String[]{"he"});

    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
```