# How to get SpeechRecognizer to return non-English strings

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm using the `SpeechRecognizer` to try to get some German strings back. I'm passing in a Google Translate German recording (e.g., "How are you?" -> "Wie geht es Ihnen?").

I've looked at several SO question/answers about how to change the language to accept something other than English but none seem to work.

Does anyone know how to do this while keeping the device's language setting to English (en-US)?

I'm able to successfully get German strings back only when I set the device's language to "de-DE".

Here's my sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    Button mSpeakBtn;
    TextView mResultTextView;
    SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Init Views
        mSpeakBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speak_btn);
        mResultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_tv);

        // Set click listener for button
        mSpeakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mResultTextView.setText("Speak now...");

                mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getApplicationContext());
                mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
                        mResultTextView.setText("Processing...");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(int error) {
                        mResultTextView.setText("ERROR: " + error);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
                        List<String> allWords = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResults:\t" + allWords.toString());
                        String result = allWords.get(0);
                        mResultTextView.setText("RESULT: '" + result + "'");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

                    }
                });

                String locale = Locale.GERMANY.toString().replace("_", "-");
                Log.d(TAG, "Locale:\t" + locale);

                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, locale);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, locale);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getApplication().getPackageName());
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
                mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've also tried it where I'm only doing this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, locale);
mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
```

But the result is the same -- getting 'English' translation of the German utterance.

Any pointers?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417439/speechrecognizer-with-google-search-version-3-6-14-1337016-cant-recognize-other ? Did you update recently?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just checked and I am running Google Search 3.6+. This is a very annoying bug. Hope they fix soon!