# How to set Speech Recognizer input to Russian?

Tags: speech

I want to change Russian as input language but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea how i can do that?

```html
Intent i5 = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        
        i5.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "ru-RU");
           i5.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak");
           startActivityForResult(i5, check);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SpeechRecognizer with Google Search version 3.6.14.1337016 can't recognize other voice language except default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417439/speechrecognizer-with-google-search-version-3-6-14-1337016-cant-recognize-other)

Comment: Thank you Mr Nikolay Shmyrev.